# Setting up jQuery noConflict with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've been follow the official RequireJS tutorial [here](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap) without any luck. I think I might be misunderstanding something very fundamental.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined
```

This is the folder structure:

```
/scripts/libs
    jquery.js           // current latest version
    jquery-private.js
    require.js          // current latest version
/scripts
    main.js
page.html
```

The `page.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />
    <title>Questions</title>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    hi
</body>
</html>
```

The `main.js` is as follows:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'scripts/libs',
    map: {

        '*': {'jquery': 'jquery-private'},
        'jquery-private': 'jquery'
            // I have also tried this line instead, as in the tutorial:
            // 'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
});

require(['jquery'], function(jq) {

    alert('test');
});
```

And, the `jquery-private.js` is as follows:

```
define(['jquery'], function(jq) {

    return jq.noConflict(true);
});
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. I think it's a settings error of some sort. The `jq` variable in the `jquery-private.js` file is undefined.

If you have any questions, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I was able to get it working using this as the `require.config`:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'scripts/libs',
    paths: {

        'jquery': 'jquery'
    },
    map: {

        '*': {'jquery': 'jquery-private'},
        'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
});
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version without **map**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/libs',

    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.11.1.min'
    }
});

require(['jquery-private'], function ($) {
    console.log('jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery)
});
```

And version with **map** configuration

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/lib',

  paths: {
    'print': '../patch/print',
    'jquery': '../patch/jquery-1.9.0'
  },

  map: {
    '*': {jQuery: 'jquery'},
    'jQuery': { 'jquery': 'jQuery' }
  }
})

require(['jQuery'], function($) {
  console.log('jQuery version: ' + jQuery.fn.jquery);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof. I was using map for two reasons. The first was because the tutorial used it, and the second was that I wanted to refer to jquery as 'jquery' instead of having to write 'jquery-private' every time. Using a combination of what you posted, I was able to get it working! Thank you!